# Does OSMF support embedded audio tracks in a video or only external audio tracks?

Tags: audio, osmf

Does OSMF support embedded audio tracks in a video or only external audio tracks? As far as I've read it can only play external audio tracks that is mentioned in the manifest file. What if a video has embedded audio tracks? Can OSMF switch between the embedded audio tracks?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it supports embedded audio, but I've only ever used external audio tracks, so don't quote me on that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Could you suggest me some links on which I can get more info on embedded tracks. I read the OSMF developer guide which has the following chunk of code:if (_player.hasAlternativeAudio)
{ for (var index:int=0; index<_player.numAlternativeAudioStreams;
index++)
{ var item:StreamingItem=_player.getAlternativeAudioItemAt(index);
trace("[LBA] [", item.info.language, "]", item.info.label);
}. But as far as I understand this will only get the external audios as present in the manifest.